# Html-table, using a cell value for external Google-searchlink, works only with one searchword

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, innerhtml

I have a html table, link below. In each rows last cell there's a Google-button, which performs a Google-search with the value of the rows first cell. Opens it in a new tab.

This works perfectly when there's only one word in the first cell. When searching with multiple words, example "alter table" I get the error "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal". Any advice on this?

I've tried swapping innerHTML to textContent and innerText, but no use.

http://kajlax.mbnet.fi/Projects/sql/

```
let table = document.getElementById("sqlTable");
let rows = table.rows;

for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length -1; i++) {
rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML = "<button target='_blank' onclick=window.open('https://www.google.fi/search?q=sql+"+rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML+"') class='ui primary icon compact mini button'><i class='inverted google icon'></i>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script. It will helps you.

```
for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length -1; i++) {
str = rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
res = str.replace(" ", "+");
rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML = "<button target='_blank' onclick=window.open('https://www.google.fi/search?q=sql+"+res+"') class='ui primary icon compact mini button'><i class='inverted google icon'></i>";
}
```